# 伝聞を表さない、文末に来る「という」の働き

Tags: usage, colloquial-language, particle-と

最近あるホラーゲームの実況を見ている時、一人の実況者がある段階をクリアした後、笑ってこう言っていました。

> しかも、結構やっぱ、懐中電灯なくても全然暗くないっていう

前にも、一緒にプレイしている相手が何回か「懐中電灯がなくても暗くない」と意外そうに言っていたので、そちらに関連があると思いますが、この「という」の働きはわからないのです。「ということ」「らしい」「と言われる」を意味する文末の「という」は知っているのですが、ここには当てはまるとは思いにくいです。なぜなら、誰かを引用しているとしても、その人は一緒にいる相手なので、少しおかしいのですよね。でしたらどういう働きをしているのですか。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: This paper discusses this usage of という/っていう: 上村昂史（2014）「[『言いさし文』における『という』の諸用法 : 終助詞的用法に関する一考察](https://doi.org/10.14989/196762)」

Comment: @jukbot Fantastic find! Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are criticizing, or find it funny that it is 懐中電灯なくても全然暗くない. It's a bit like writing `*shrug*`.

Similar examples include:

> よりによって今壊れるっていう
>   Out of all possible times, it chooses to break at this very moment `*shrug*`

.

> お前は誰やねんっていう（笑）
>   I was like, who the hell are you lol

It's an invitation to agree to/sympathize with the speaker. Grammatically something else is supposed to come after ていう, but it intentionally trails off (inviting the listener to fill the rest). Some find it annoying (similar to saying "I'm like").